# Erro requisição AJAX - ASP. Net e JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net, webforms

Tenho um arquivo aspx onde criei um *script* com uma chamada AJAX para executar o método `populaGridMembros` na tabela `gwMembros`, o método está funcionando perfeitamente e retornando uma string no formato JSON, porém, quando executo a `$.ajax` não funciona, ele entra no código mais não ocorre o *success* e ele pula para o erro. Gostaria de ajuda para resolver este problema.

ASPX:

```
<table id="gwdMembros" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped" data-selection="true" data-multi-select="true" data-row-select="true" data-keep-selection="true">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-column-id="NOME">Nome</th>
                <th data-column-id="SOBRENOME">Sobrenome</th>
                <th data-column-id="RG">RG</th>
                <th data-column-id="CPF">CPF</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tabela">
        </tbody>
    </table>
 </div>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.bootgrid.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "membros.aspx/populaGridMembros",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {},
            success: function () {
                populaTabela(data);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
                alert("Erro");
            }
        });
    });

    function populaTabela(dados) {
        var result = JSON.parse(dados);
        var out;
        for (var it = 0; it < result.length; it++) {
            out += "<tr><td>" + result[it].NOME + "</td></tr>" +
                    "<tr><td>" + result[it].SOBRENOME + "</td></tr>" +
                    "<tr><td>" + result[it].RG + "</td></tr>" +
                    "<tr><td>" + result[it].CPF + "</td></tr>";
        }

        document.getElementById("tabela").innerHTML = out;
    }

    $(function () {
        function init() {
            $("#gwMembros").bootgrid();
        }

        init();

        $("#init").on("click", init);
    });
</script>
```

No aspx.cs desse arquivo tenho o seguinte código:

```
public static string populaGridMembros()
    {
        modelo = new ModelGestaoEclesiasticaDataContext();

        try
        {
            var sourceMembros = from listMembros in modelo.TB_MEMBROs
                                select new
                                {
                                    NOME = listMembros.NOME,
                                    SOBRENOME = listMembros.SOBRENOME,
                                    RG = listMembros.RG,
                                    CPF = listMembros.CPF
                                };

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sourceMembros);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            modelo.Dispose();
        }
    }

    protected void addMembro_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Cadastros/cadMembro.aspx");
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Faltou a envio da variavel data como paramento da função:

```
success: function () {
                populaTabela(data);
            },
```

Dessa forma fica

```
success: function (data) {
                populaTabela(data);
            },
```

Comment: Bom dia Jao Assy, obrigado pela ajuda. Entretanto, mesmo colocando o data, que realmente eu havia esquecido de colocar quando postei o código aqui, não funciona. Não estou conseguindo enxergar o erro.

Comment: Bom, o parametro success do JQUERY.ajax ele exige que os atributos .status e .readyState do objeto jqXHR (passado pelo function(data) sejam respectivamente, 200 e 4. Caso contrário não executa, no entanto existe um outro atributo COMPLETE: que aceita qualquer status ou readyState. neste caso ficaria -> complete: function(data){ //TODO } teste se ele executa dessa maneira, por favor mostre o JS errorLog do navegador.